# .NET Core Model Not Binding

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a .NET Core API POST method that accepts an instance of a model. I'm testing out my API via Postman and when I send a json-formatted object to my api I am seeing in the logs references to model binding. I am thinking the model binding is not working properly. Here is the output from postman:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $.damaged | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 41.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThowJsonException(String message, Utf8JsonReader& reader, String path)
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType, Utf8JsonReader& reader, String path)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyInfoNotNullable`3.Read(JsonTokenType tokenType, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.HandleValue(JsonTokenType tokenType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, Span`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJ...
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.968351695.1527270246; __utma=111872281.968351695.1527270246.1529431622.1530048579.3
Host: localhost:5001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://coohjcphdfgbiolnekdpbcijmhambjff
Content-Length: 194
```

In Postman I am sending my json like so:

```
{ "puDate": "0001-01-01", "damaged": "No", "boxed": "No", "pieceCount": 0, "address1": "123", "address2": "", "address3": "", "zip": "12345", "city": "SomeCity", "state": "AB", "po": 534560349, "createDate": "2019-06-06", "createdBy": "Me" }
```

My WebAPI action (default scaffold)

```
// POST: api/ReturnShipmentQueues
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ReturnShipmentQueue>> PostReturnShipmentQueue(ReturnShipmentQueue returnShipmentQueue)
        {
            _context.ReturnShipmentQueue.Add(returnShipmentQueue);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (ReturnShipmentQueueExists(returnShipmentQueue.FkPonumber))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetReturnShipmentQueue", new { id = returnShipmentQueue.FkPonumber }, returnShipmentQueue);
        }
```

And of course the model:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication12.Models
{
    public partial class ReturnShipmentQueue
    {
        [Key]
        public long FkPonumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime PickupDate { get; set; }
        public bool Damaged { get; set; }
        public bool Boxed { get; set; }
        public int Pieces { get; set; }
        public string Puaddress1 { get; set; }
        public string Puaddress2 { get; set; }
        public string Puaddress3 { get; set; }
        public string Pucity { get; set; }
        public string Pustate { get; set; }
        public string Puzip { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm a bit new to the API way of developing but am I supposed to specify some config settings for this to work or do I need something else?

Answer (score 2):

Boolean is either 'true' or 'false'

your example has a 'No', please check your Boolean fields

```
"damaged": "No"
"boxed": "No"
```

Comment: Also to note that the names of the properties in the json to not accurately reflect the property names in the object, e.g. "Puaddress1" in the object, but "address1" in the JSON.